# align* inside enumerate*

Tags: align, amsmath, enumitem

It seems that using `align*` inside `enumerate*` results in PDFLaTeX hanging. Can anyone explain the reason and/or suggest a workaround

Minimal example

```
\documentclass[11pt]{extarticle}   
\usepackage[inline, shortlabels]{enumitem}

\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate*}
\item
\begin{align*}
abc &= def
\end{align*}
\end{enumerate*}

\end{document}
```

To explain what I need this for. I use `align*` to create equations with annotated steps - for example for fill-in-the-blank equation solving. I use the following macro to do so

```
\newcommand\rightcomment[5][0.3]%
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
   \draw[-stealth]
     ($({pic cs:#4}|-{pic cs:#2})+(#1,0)$)
     .. controls +(0.2,-0.05) and +(0.2,0.1) ..
     node[right,align=left]{#5}
     ($({pic cs:#4}|-{pic cs:#3})+(#1,0.1)$);
   \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

\newcommand\leftcomment[5][-0.1]%
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
   \draw[-stealth]
     ($({pic cs:#4}|-{pic cs:#2})+(#1,0)$)
     .. controls +(-0.2,-0.05) and +(-0.2,0.1) ..
     node[left,align=right]{#5}
     ($({pic cs:#4}|-{pic cs:#3})+(#1,0.1)$);
   \end{tikzpicture}%
  }


\newcommand\twostep[9]{
\begin{align*}
\tikzmark{la#1} #2 &= #3 \tikzmark{ra#1}\\
\tikzmark{lb#1} #5 &= #6 \tikzmark{rb#1}\\
\tikzmark{lc#1} #8 &= #9 \tikzmark{rc#1}
\end{align*}
\leftcomment{la#1}{lb#1}{la#1}{$(#4)$}
\leftcomment{lb#1}{lc#1}{la#1}{$(#7)$}
\rightcomment{ra#1}{rb#1}{ra#1}{$(#4)$}
\rightcomment{rb#1}{rc#1}{ra#1}{$(#7)$}  
  }
```

Which is used like:

```
    \twostep{a}{5y + 1}{21}
    {-1}{5y}{20}
    {\div 5}{y}{4}
```

This renders output like:

[image]

I then use the following macro to layout enumerated questions in a grid in a row-major order

```
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage[inline, shortlabels]{enumitem}

\newenvironment{tabbedenum}[1]
{\noindent\NumTabs{#1}\begin{enumerate*}[itemjoin={\tab}]}{\end{enumerate*}}
```

Which gives me a nice grid-structure of questions in rows:

[image]

Comment: An `align` would necessarily set its content as a display, thereby disrupting the "nice grid-structure"; it seems counter-intuitive for your usage.

Comment: @Werner - I'm sorry I'm not a very advanced TeX user - I `align*` keeps the typeset math inline as opposed to `align`. Actually if I switch for `align` I get exactly the same problem. $x = y$ and `$$ x = y$$` work fine. `begin{equation}` or `\[` result in a "bad math environment deliminator" error.

Comment: @maninalift: `align` is similar to `align*` - the former just adds equation numbers while the latter doesn't. `$x = y$` is consider inline math, while [`\[`...`\]`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5764) sets a single equation in display math mode, just like `align`/`align*`. My original comment merely states that you're switching from inline enumeration (`enumerate*`) to display math mode, which defeats the style of having an inline enumeration.

Comment: `align*` does not set math inline it is a display environment.  `$` is for inline math,

Comment: a quick compile of the example you posted yields the error
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.12 \end{align*}
only after that does it hang (loop).  instead of `align*`, use `$\begin{aligned}[t] ... \end{aligned}$`.  (if this gives the result you want, please provide a more informative example, and i'll write an answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`align*` is the wrong tool: you need `aligned`.

Also, you need to reserve enough space for the arrows and labels, because `\tikzmark` won't make their width known.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[inline, shortlabels]{enumitem}

\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark}

\newcommand\rightcomment[5][0.3]%
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
   \draw[-stealth]
     ($({pic cs:#4}|-{pic cs:#2})+(#1,0)$)
     .. controls +(0.2,-0.05) and +(0.2,0.1) ..
     node[right,align=left]{#5}
     ($({pic cs:#4}|-{pic cs:#3})+(#1,0.1)$);
   \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

\newcommand\leftcomment[5][-0.1]%
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
   \draw[-stealth]
     ($({pic cs:#4}|-{pic cs:#2})+(#1,0)$)
     .. controls +(-0.2,-0.05) and +(-0.2,0.1) ..
     node[left,align=right]{#5}
     ($({pic cs:#4}|-{pic cs:#3})+(#1,0.1)$);
   \end{tikzpicture}%
  }


\newcommand\twostep[9]{%
  $\qquad\qquad\begin{aligned}[t]
  \tikzmark{la#1} #2 &= #3 \tikzmark{ra#1}\\
  \tikzmark{lb#1} #5 &= #6 \tikzmark{rb#1}\\
  \tikzmark{lc#1} #8 &= #9 \tikzmark{rc#1}
  \end{aligned}\qquad\qquad$%
  \leftcomment{la#1}{lb#1}{la#1}{$(#4)$}%
  \leftcomment{lb#1}{lc#1}{la#1}{$(#7)$}%
  \rightcomment{ra#1}{rb#1}{ra#1}{$(#4)$}%
  \rightcomment{rb#1}{rc#1}{ra#1}{$(#7)$}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{enumerate*}
\item
\twostep{a}{5y + 1}{21}
        {-1}{5y}{20}
        {\div 5}{y}{4}
\item
\twostep{b}{5y + 1}{21}
        {-1}{5y}{20}
        {\div 5}{y}{4}
\end{enumerate*}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you - this worked for me. Credit also to @barbara-beeton who posted the same suggestion in a comment on my question.

Answer (score 2):

Try the `unboxed` mode:

```
\begin{enumerate*}[mode=unboxed]
\item
\begin{align*}
abc &= def
\end{align*}
\end{enumerate*}
```

It was very unfortunate I decided to make the `boxed` mode the default.

Comment: The answer I accepted works well for me but I will give this a try as it might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need `TikZ` for that: some arrows from `MnSymbol` and an `alignedat` environment will do the job.

As to  the horizontal enumerate, the natural environment for that should be the `tasks` package and its eponymous environment. Unfortunately, it can't be nested. I propose another solution, based on the `shortlst` package, which defines a `shortenumerate` environment, that I tweaked in order to make the number of columns an optional argument (`3` by default).

Note this package is not part of TeX Live nor MiKTeX for licensing reasons, I believe, so you'll have to download it from CTAN and install it by hand in your TeXMF-local directory.

Here is an example:

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{extarticle}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage[inline, shortlabels]{enumitem}
    \usepackage{tasks}
    \usepackage{amssymb, mathtools}
    \usepackage{relsize}
    \DeclareFontFamily{U} {MnSymbolA}{}
    \DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyA} {U} {MnSymbolA}{m}{n}
    \SetSymbolFont{MnSyA} {bold}{U} {MnSymbolA}{b}{n}
    \DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolA}{m}{n}{
    <-6> MnSymbolA5
   <6-7> MnSymbolA6
   <7-8> MnSymbolA7
   <8-9> MnSymbolA8
   <9-10> MnSymbolA9
  <10-12> MnSymbolA10
  <12-> MnSymbolA12}{}
    \DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolA}{b}{n}{
    <-6> MnSymbolA-Bold5
   <6-7> MnSymbolA-Bold6
   <7-8> MnSymbolA-Bold7
   <8-9> MnSymbolA-Bold8
   <9-10> MnSymbolA-Bold9
  <10-12> MnSymbolA-Bold10
  <12-> MnSymbolA-Bold12}{}
        \DeclareMathSymbol{\rcurvearrowdown}{\mathrel}{MnSyA}{"C3}%{"FD}
        \DeclareMathSymbol{\lcurvearrowdown}{\mathrel}{MnSyA}{"BB}%

    \usepackage{shortlst}
    \newenvironment{tabenumerate}[1][3]{%
    \renewcommand{\theenumii}{$\alph{enumii}$}
    \settowidth{\labelwidth}{\labelenumii}%
    \setlength{\leftmarginii}{\dimexpr\parindent + \labelwidth + \labelsep\relax}%
    \setlength{\shortitemwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth/#1-\labelwidth-2\labelsep\relax}%
    \begin{shortenumerate}}%
    {\end{shortenumerate}}%

    \newcommand{\leftcomment}[1]{\raisebox{1.2ex}[0pt]{$ (#1)$}\raisebox{0.9ex}[0pt]{$\scalebox{1.4}{$ \rcurvearrowdown $}\: $}}
    \newcommand{\rightcomment}[1]{\raisebox{0.9ex}[0pt]{$\scalebox{1.4}{$ \: \lcurvearrowdown $}$}\raisebox{1.2ex}[0pt]{$(#1)$}}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}[labelsep = 1.3em]
    \item
    \begin{tabenumerate}[2]
    \item $ \begin{alignedat}[t]{3}
     & & 5y + 1 &= 21\\
    \leftcomment{-1}
     & & 5y & =20 & & \rightcomment{-1}\\
    \leftcomment{\div 5} & & y & =4 & & \rightcomment{\div5}
    \end{alignedat} $
    \item $ \begin{alignedat}[t]{3}
     & & 6y + 3 &= 21\\
    \leftcomment{-3}
     & & 6y & =18 & & \rightcomment{-3}\\
    \leftcomment{\div 6} & & y & =3 & & \rightcomment{\div6}
    \end{alignedat} $
    \end{tabenumerate}
    \end{enumerate}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With the non negligible consequence that *all* math symbols will change.

Comment: I have accepted the answer above as I have tested it and it answers my question directly. However, this may be a better approach in the long-run (accepting the fact I'd rather avoid an out-of-bundle package). I'm guessing also that if the lines of the equation change in height the arrows will not adapt as they do with the TiKz example.

Comment: @egreg: I tried to load only  the two symbols needed, but I didn't find their slot numbers (this doesn't seem to be documented) and it was late. This morning, I found out – counting in the documentation, and I've fixed the code (and slightly improved it: the ‘comments’ were not  quite centred w.r.t. the arrows).

Comment: @maninalift: Yes, you can't scale the MnSymbol arrows very much, as it also thickens them. Other than that, I usually prefer `pstricks` to TikZ for this kind of  extensible arrows (it's often less verbose). If you do not stick to curved arrows, you should also take a look at the `gauss` package.